# How would you create a 'manual' django migration?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I've discovered that I can set defaults for columns on a postgres database in a django project using `migrations.RunSQL('some sql')`.

I'm currently doing this by adding a column, makemigrations, then removing the column, makemigrations, and then manually modifying the migration file that is produced.

I tried copying an old migration file and then removing the old code so just the new sql could be run and got some strange errors.

```
CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0067_auto_20180509_2327, 0068_auto_20180514_0707 in csmu).
To fix them run python manage.py makemigrations --merge
```

How would you create a 'manual' django migration?

Comment: [`python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can create a manual migration by running the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name --name migration_name --empty
```

Where `app_name` corresponds to the app within your project you want to add the migration. Remember Django manages both Project and Apps (A project is a collection of configuration and apps for a particular website. A project can contain multiple apps. An app can be in multiple projects.)
And `--empty` flag is to create a migration file where you will have to add your manual migrations.

**For example**, on a project where you have an app named `api` that only has one migration file `0001_initial.py` running:

```
python manage.py makemigrations api --name migration_example --empty
```

will create a file named `0002_migration_example.py` under the directory `api/migrations/` that will look like:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.10 on 2020-05-26 20:37

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

And you should add `migrations.RunSQL('some sql').` inside operations brackets, like:

```
    operations = [
      migrations.RunSQL('some sql')
    ]
```

Comment: The migration name must be a valid Python identifier.

Comment: Mistake --name 003_some_name  instead of --name some_name. It will automatically add number according to previous migration.

Answer (score 11):

You can learn how to make migrations by investigating the automatically generated migrations, for example:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_details', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            ...,
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            ...,
        ),
        migrations.RenameModel(
            ...,
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            ...,
        ),
        migrations.RemoveModel(
            ...,
        ),
        # and so on
    ]
```

---

#### Create a manual migration file

use this command in the terminal: `python manage.py makemigrations --empty`.
Then add what you want in it.

> notice: you have to compose between the "models.py" and the manual migrations.