# Can you stop Django automatically reverting a manual Migration?

Tags: django, makemigrations

I have a Model file which has a change which isn't being picked up by DJango `makemigrations`.

I created a manual migration following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031107/1609929), but if we run makemigrations afterwards Django creates a new auto migration reverting our manual changes.

Is there a way to manually make a migration and tell DJango to ignore relevant parts of the code when generating future migrations?

Comment: Note I'm working on a bug testcase for the apparent bug causing django not to pick up the change in the first place - this Question is under the assumption that it doesn't get fixed.

Comment: "*but if we run makemigrations afterwards Django creates a new auto migration reverting our manual changes."* Can you add a minimal reproducable example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes to the models and creating a custom migration for them e.g. using [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) or [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) you can use the `state_operations` argument to reflect the changed models' state in your custom Python or SQL `operations`.